# Add products to sales quote in magento admin programmatically

Tags: php, magento, ecommerce-sales

I have customized **search product grid** as per client need(**created new grid and disabled search grid**) under sales order create page.

I have created new grid successfully after **"Items Ordered**" block.

When i click **"Add product(s) To Item"** button of my custom grid, I got product id and quantity of that selected product in my custom controller file.

I have tried to add those products to quote, Nothing has been changed. I dunno, how to add these selected products from my custom grid under "Items Ordered" block.

I have tried following code to add products to quote.

```
     $customer_id = 26; // set this to the ID of the customer.
     $customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
     $quoteObj=Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);
     $quoteObj = $quoteObj->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
     $productModel=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
     $productObj = $productModel->load($_id);
     $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
     $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
     $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
     $quoteObj->collectTotals();
     $quoteObj->save();
```

***I'm not sure, That block containing quote products or else***

Have any idea, How to add selected products to **"Items Ordered"** block in sales order create page.

Eagerly awaiting for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution after long hunt.

Just passed products array to productGridAddSelected() method like below

**`order.productGridAddSelected(products);`**

products array must be like

**products[product_id]= quantity;**